# how to storing result as dataframe from for-loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to get the .csv output with the grade regulation as `A`, `B+`, `B`, ....

The input data be like:

```
name,score
A, 55
B, 30
.
.
.
```

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Calculate grade regulation
def grading(x):
  if x >=90 and x <= 100:
    return 'A'
  elif x >= 85 and x <= 89.99:
    return 'B+'
  elif x >= 80 and x <= 84.99:
    return 'B'
  elif x >= 75 and x <= 79.99:
    return 'C+'
  elif x >= 70 and x <= 74.99:
    return 'C'
  elif x >= 65 and x <= 69.99:
    return 'D+'
  elif x >= 60 and x <= 64.99:
    return 'D'
  else:
    return 'E'

#import data from google drive
student_list = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/PYTHON CLASS/example_name-score.csv')
df = []
df = pd.DataFrame(student_list)

for  index, row in df.iterrows():
    df = grading(row['score'])
    df.append(df.strip())
```

I'm trying to add the list of df into the new column of dataframe but there are error appearing as

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: Don't loop here, try something like `df['grade'] = df['score'].apply(grading)`

Comment: Also you should check [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) to replace `grading`

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the `AttributeError` because df is assigned  to hold the value of the grading function for each row, this value is a str and not the original DataFrame anymore.

What you should do instead is not assigning the whole df to to the value and rather (and what you initially meant to do) is to set the value for a new columns like the following (and as mentioned in the comment section:

```
df['grading'] = df['score'].apply(grading)
```

The **[apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)** method is very useful for applying a function or lambda function for row-wise assignment. The apply takes care of the iteration. Therefore, no need to loop the df yourself.

It is important to emphasize that the operation is set to df['grading'] which is a new [`Pandas.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) (after assignment check it yourself using type(df['grading']). The series is the Array-like objects that is used as column in `Pandas.DataFrame`

Comment: Thank you. that's made me understand clearly.